# How can I access the layout in a class extending Activity that is to be subclassed by another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm using a SideNavigationBar (in addition to ActionBarSherlock) in my Android App, and I'm a dilemma about how to go about creating a class extending SherlockActivity.

Since all my activities have a SideNavigation bar and a similarly themed ABS, it makes sense that I create generic subclass of SherlockActivity that initializes the SideNavigation and ABS that will be constant throughout my Activities, and then extend this subclass for all of my unique Activities (Home, settings, etc.). So, for example, HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity, which extends SherlockActivity. ActionBarActivity is where I want all the customizing of the ABS and initializing the Sidebar to occur.

The problem is that I don't know how to access the layout from my ActionBarActivity, which is necessary since that's where I get the SidenavigationBar (using findViewById). If I was doing this in HomeActivity, i would access the layout using findViewById after setting the content view (setContentView), but since I never set the content view in ActionBarActivity, i'm not quite sure how I can access the SidenavigationBar from the layout.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but since I never set the content view in ActionBarActivity, i'm not quite sure how I can access the SidenavigationBar from the layout.

If I understand your question, HomeActivity calls `setContentView()` but you want to access the layout in it's parent ActionBarActivity?
Then simply make a new method in ActionBarActivity (perhaps `initSideNavigationBar()`).  This new method can call `findViewById()` just like before as long as you call it after `setContentView()` in HomeActivity.

Comment: Will I have to pass anything to the method? Because I tried putting super.onCreate() (in HomeActivity) AFTER setContentView, with hopes that then I'd be able to access the layout, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Just realized I as being stupid (didn't add the Sidebar to the view... and some other stuff). Regardless, thank you, answer accepted!